# Getting cli arguments through reflection in java

Tags: java, reflection

Is there any way to access the arguments in the args array other than as parameters to main? I'm tinkering with a [Disgruntled Bomb](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/The-Disgruntled-Bomb.aspx) in java and I want to be able to get the cli arguments and call the main function with them in random order or something like that.

```
public class Bomb{

  static {
    main(new String[]{"arg"});
    System.exit(0);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    for(int i = 0; i < args.length; i++){
      System.out.printf("arg %d: %s%n",i,args[i]);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Why would you call `System.exit(0)` in a static initializer?

Comment: Why is there a static initializer in the first place...?

Answer (score 4):

On Sun's JDK, you can access the `sun.java.command` property:

```
String args = System.getProperty("sun.java.command");
```

However, you have to split the arguments yourself, and it's also not very portable to other JVMs.

Comment: Your answer is also applicable to IBM's implementation.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if it what you are looking for, but the Apache CLI (Command Line Interface) lets you pass arguments in the "old" Unix way

```
-nameOfArgument1 valueOfArgument1 -nameOfArgument2 valueOfArgument2....
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implement a main method in another class, and use that to call the original main with the randomization you require? Or does the call need to be exactly the same? In that case, how would you stop the call to main inself?